# into list vs. into vector in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, functional-programming

Can you explain this behaviour in Clojure ?

```
user=> (into [1 2 3] ["a" "b"])
[1 2 3 "a" "b"]
```

but

```
user=> (into '(1 2 3) ["a" "b"])
("b" "a" 1 2 3)
```

It is understandable that `into` with vector appends the items but why using `into` with list first reverts the items order and then prepends it to the list ?

Answer (score 8):

`into` uses `conj` to add items into the source collection. `conj` appends items to the front for lists and to the end for vectors. Clojure lists are immutable singly-linked lists, so adding to the end of the list would be an O(n) operation. Insertion at the front is a constant-time operation.